# Can I use a paired t-test to assess whether there are statistically significant differences between the backtesting results of two forecasting models?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, t-test, cross-validation, model-comparison

I developed a new forecasting model with the aim of replacing an older model. I conducted 12 backtests and need to predict only one quarter ahead. Overall, my new model performs better than the older model, but there are instances where it performs worse. I believe that performing a paired t-test would be appropriate to determine if the resulting error of the forecasted values of my new model significantly differ from those of the old model. In this scenario, the paired samples would consist of the error of the forecasted values of both models for each quarter. Does this reasoning make sense? I tried to search for examples in literature but could not readily find any.

Edit: Each backtest date has 15 forecasted subcomponents. So altogether there are (15 * 12 = 180) forecasted values that I am comparing.

E.g.

|  | group | year_quarter | error_new | error_old |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 2019-Q3 | -2 | 4 |
| 1 | B | 2019-Q3 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | C | 2019-Q3 | 1 | 2.5 |
| 3 | D | 2019-Q3 | 6 | -4 |